# How much older is Anzu compared to Kaoru at the end of the movie "Natsu e no Tunnel, Sayonara no Deguchi"?

Tags: the-tunnel-to-summer

When Anzu meets Kaoru in that tunnel, she tells him it's been 8 years since they last met. But when they leave the tunnel together, after sharing a kiss, it has been 13 years and 102 days since he entered the cave. This should mean that Anzu has also spent 5 years in the tunnel searching for Kaoru. Since 1 hour in it equals 100 days outside, she spent 18 hours searching for him. So, Kaoru should have collapsed very far from the entrance of the tunnel.

Did I understand that correctly? From what I've read on the Internet, some say there's an age gap of 8 years, and some say 13 years. Someone even claims there's no age gap at all as, apparently, you also age in that tunnel. I don't think that's the case, though, as Kaoru looks no different before and after entering the tunnel (and 13 years should make a notable difference).

Maybe it should also be said that I've only watched the fan translation. And it doesn't seem to be entirely accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 years difference is correct, Touno was in the tunnel for 13 years while Hanashiro has been inside for 5.

Touno enters the tunnel on August 2, 2005 in order to get his little sister back. Note the date on his final text message to Hanashiro,

[image: Touno's last text before entering the tunnel]

While living in the tunnel's conjured reality where his sister is still alive, Touno continuously receives text messages from Hanashiro who never forgets about him which eventually causes him to accept his sister's death and return to the outside to be with Hanashiro. He texts her that he loves her from inside the tunnel and starts running back before tripping and passing out. Hanashiro receives Touno's text on May 1, 2013,

[image: Touno's text from inside the tunnel]

which causes her to go into the tunnel to look for him. She presumably has to run pretty deep into the tunnel to find him and then waits until he awakens before they reconcile and head back out together.

In the end when the two of them leave the tunnel they state its been 13 years and 102 days (since Touno went into the tunnel), the exact date isn't given but that should be November 12, 2018.

EDIT: I just read the manga, haven't read the light novel but I assume it and the manga are similar and overall the movie cut a lot of content. Regarding the idea that there's no age gap and both Touno and Hanashiro are 30 in the end (they were both 17 at the start). They did some experiments with the tunnel to see how it worked and confirmed the tunnel causes time dilation (i.e. time actually passes slower inside the tunnel compared to outside) rather than accelerating the perception time (i.e. time passes at the same speed inside or outside the tunnel it just feels faster inside). Hanashiro spells out their actual ages in the end over drinks with Kawasaki and Kaga (this is past the ending of the movie),

[image: Hanashiro explains their ages]

Hanashiro says Touno is physically 17 (13 years in the tunnel) and she is 22 (8 years in the tunnel). You'll notice the age gap is 5 years not 8 here but that's because the manga flips the intervals, Touno still goes to the tunnel August 2, 2005 and leaves 13 years later but Hanashiro runs in after him 5 years later rather than 8. 8 years (as per the dates on the text messages) is still correct for the movie.

Comment: huh 22? years instead of 30 a 17 plus 13 years in the tunnel sorry at the end of a sentence like that I don't understand 

Comment: @VandiAkhsan_ at the end of the manga (and I assume the LN as well) due to the time dilation effects of the tunnel Hanashiro is physically 22 (25 in the movie), Touno is physically 17 while their friends who've never gone into the tunnel are 30. They should all be the same age (30) but since time passes much slower for people in the tunnel the  13 years Touno was gone only felt like 2 days to him